# I need to pass the value of userName from Spring controller to JSP page

Tags: java, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitlogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String checkLoginDetails(@ModelAttribute("login") LoginBean loginBean, BindingResult result) {

    if (service.validate(loginBean)) {
        //model.addAttribute("userName", " " + loginBean.getUserName());
        return "success";
    }

    return "invalid";
}
```

But I'm not allowed to add other parameters to the function.I need to pass userName to the "success.jsp" using Spring. I'm new to spring,plz help me with this.

Comment: well are you doing a request or handling request (sending a response)?

Comment: Return a `ModelAndView` (with the attribute set) instead of a `String` view name.

Comment: I'm getting a form values filled by users. And after validation I need to send the user name to the another page("success").   Well I can use Model to set the attribute. But I'm forced to use the given signature, can't alter that.

Comment: Then you're out of luck. (Or just use `login.userName` in your view.)

Comment: I'm new to spring. I don't know how to use that.can you help me with that.

Comment: Why are you saying you are forced to use the given signature? Who decided on that? Are there other methods using it?

Comment: If I change the signature then during the evaluation, I get less marks.

Comment: Is there any other way to bind the data with "success" view.

Comment: Even I can add a new function.

Comment: You could consider ModelAttribute at method level, but how would you get the username from the bean? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-and-the-modelattribute-annotation

I think the requirement not to change the method signature is flawed.

Comment: yeah, I tried and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: But directly using " ${login.userName}" also worked. Don't know why.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a `final Model model` in your method signature. Therefore your signature should look like following:

```
public String checkLoginDetails(final Model model, @ModelAttribute("login") LoginBean loginBean, BindingResult result)
```

Then you can use the `Model` parameter to add further attributes. For example:

```
model.addAttribute(ModelAttributeConstants.SUCCESSFUL, false);
```

or

```
model.addAttribute("successful", false);
```

Or to use your case

```
model.addAttribute("userName", " " + loginBean.getUserName());
```

I prefer the way using constants as I can use them in every place without thinking about the correct spelling. For sure you have to define you own constants class and names :)

Comment: But I'm forced to use the given signature, can't alter that.

Comment: Okay, then I misunderstood your question. That means that you can also not alter the return type of the method?

Comment: yeah, can't change

Comment: But I can add a new function to the controller.